# In Docker tomcat container tomcat is not running

Tags: docker, tomcat7, dockerfile

i have made a **Dockerfile for tomcat** so that when I run container then container automatically start.
But after running container i checked tomcat is not started but container is running.

### my Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM ubuntu

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /opt/soft/apache-tomcat-8.0.30

RUN mkdir -p /opt/soft/jdk1.8.0_65

COPY apache-tomcat-8.0.30 /opt/soft/apache-tomcat-8.0.30

COPY jdk1.8.0_65 /opt/soft/jdk1.8.0_65

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/soft/jdk1.8.0_65
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/opt/soft/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/bin

VOLUME ["/opt/soft/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/"]

EXPOSE 7070

WORKDIR /opt/soft/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/bin

CMD ["catalina.sh", "start"]
```

Comment: You don't need to do `USER root`. You're already root. Also if you're just using Tomcat then you may be interested in looking into the Java or Tomcat base images rather than Ubuntu.

Comment: 1.how can i say i am in root without setting user in Dockerfile.
2.is something going wrong in Dockerfile.
3.after running container i checked using "ps -ef |grep java" ,then i found there is no tomcat running.but generally  it shoud run during creation or running of container? because i set CMD in Dockerfile.

Comment: You are root by default in the container.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your CMD should be like this.

   ```
   CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
   ```

   As the CMD is the main process running inside your container. Once it  stops/exits/completes its execution the container will be stopped. So you need to select the CMD which will run infinitely. Here `run` will start the tomcat and `tail` the logs infinitely.
2. Since you are not changing default HTTP port for tomcat you need to use 8080.

   ```
   EXPOSE 8080
   ```

   You can access it with 7070 if you explicitly run the container 
   with

   `docker run -d -p 7070:8080 <tomcat_image>`
3. If you start your container with `docker run -d tomcat bash`, bash will be your CMD in the container and the CMD you given in Dockerfile will be overriden. So you need to run your container without overriding the default CMD.

   ```
   docker run -d -p 7070:8080 <IMAGE> <CMD>
   docker run -d -p 7070:8080 mytomcat
   ```

In case your container running and still you are not able to access, check for the tomcat logs.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that i changed default port to 7070,and i tried with CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"] but it didn't work

Comment: @PrakashSingh, How are you starting container? Can you share docker run command?

Comment: docker run -d -p 7070:7070 <imageid>

Comment: Can you check for the logs `docker logs <container id>`?